# Inserting data from existing queries. Why its not showing up?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to insert values into a matching table in my database. However the values are not showing.What is wrong?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, job_title, no_of_vacancy, assigned FROM student_details, job_details WHERE student_details.jobscope1 = job_details.jobscope AND student_details.jobscope1 = 'IT';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 

    $student = $row['name'];
    $company = $row['job_title'];
    $vacancy = $row['no_of_vacancy'];
    $assigned= $row['assigned'];


    if ($vacancy == $assigned) {

        $result2 = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO matching (name, job_title) VALUES ('$student','$company') FROM student_details,job_details WHERE student_details.jobscope1 = job_details.jobscope AND student_details.jobscope1 = 'IT';");
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);


        $result3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM matching;");
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

        echo    "<table border='1'>
                <tr>
                <th>Student</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                </tr>";

        while($row3= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row3['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row3['job_title']. "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

}}}

?>
```

Comment: You probably need select near `VALUES ('$student','$company') SELECT * FROM ....`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the  $result2 variable?!

Comment: I want to reflect result data into result2 which is a table in a database